# Set Node_ENV in ASP.Net Core using Visual Studio

Tags: webpack, asp.net-core

Sorry I'm new to webpack,

I'm wondering how can I set the "process.env.NODE_ENV" of webpack in launchSettings.json?

And how does launchSettings.json relate to Solution Configuration?